# How to trigger user-exit EXIT_SAPMIWO0_020 via BAPI or FM?

Tags: abap, bapi

I'm creating and updating my PM notifications via `BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_CREATE` and `BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_DATA_MODIFY` respectively.

`BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_CREATE` triggers user-exit **EXIT_SAPLIQS0_017** (QQMA0025), but `BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_DATA_MODIFY` does ***not*** trigger user-exit **EXIT_SAPMIWO0_020** (QQMA0014).

I was wondering if there is another BAPI or FM that triggers the user-exit for saving the notification and triggering the user-exit.

If not, what are my other options? Would an explicit enhancement be the next best thing?

This is what Enhancement Spot `ES_SAPLIWOPM` looks like. Does this mean only `BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_DATA_DELETE` is supported?

[image]

Comment: Just checked on my system and it looks like this exit doesn't fire from `BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_DATA_MODIFY`, only from dialog mode. Stick to enhancements

Answer (score 0):

you could use the enhancement spot `ES_SAPLIWOPM`, it offers three enhancement points within `BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_DATA_MODIFY`. The enhancement spot doesn't seem to be limited to SAP internal use, so you could use it to implement your requirements. It also offers enhancement points for BAPI `BAPI_ALM_NOTIF_CREATE`, which would allow you to implement your requirements for create and update scenarios in the same technology.

Regarding the user exit from extension `QQMA0014`, the function module is contained in module pool `SAPMIWO0` and seems to be called by a few function modules and from dynpro logic, but I'm not sure they are meant to be called from outside their regular dynpro scope. Often those function modules need quite a bit of preparation to work correctly. I would stick with the BAPIs, as they are clearly meant for this purpose and have extension points to implement additional requirements, which is always a big bonus in terms of extension maintenance.

edit: the enhancement spot is present in ECC 6.0 EHP8, I'm not sure about previous releases.

Comment: I've added a new picture. Could you help me clarify, please?

Comment: which release are you on? I only have access to an EHP8 system and that has 10 or 12 enhancement points in that enhancement spot, for several BAPI function modules. If you're on an earlier release, you may not have those available to you. In that case, unless you find some other exit available on your system, you're left with the explicit enhancement (or modifying the SAP standard, which of course isn't recommended and unsupported)

Comment: On my EHP8 I have 15 enh. points with all possible FMs, so this is definitely older release OP has

Answer (score -1):

Can you check if any BAdi is getting triggered as well.

I think badi NOTIF_EVENT_POST is triggered after exit QQMA0014.

Regards